# tensorflow federated tff tutorial hang in the learning process

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

```
total_clients = len(train_data.client_ids)


def train(rounds, noise_multiplier, clients_per_round, data_frame):
# Using the `dp_aggregator` here turns on differential privacy with adaptive
# clipping.
   aggregation_factory = tff.learning.model_update_aggregator.dp_aggregator(
   noise_multiplier, clients_per_round)
```

## We use Poisson subsampling which gives slightly tighter privacy guarantees

## compared to having a fixed number of clients per round. The actual number of

## clients per round is stochastic with mean clients_per_round.

```
  sampling_prob = clients_per_round / total_clients
```

## Build a federated averaging process.

## Typically a non-adaptive server optimizer is used because the noise in the

## updates can cause the second moment accumulators to become very large

## prematurely.

```
 learning_process = tff.learning.algorithms.build_unweighted_fed_avg(
    my_model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.01),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.03, momentum=0.9),
    model_aggregator=aggregation_factory)

 eval_process = tff.learning.algorithms.build_fed_eval(my_model_fn)
```

## Training loop.

```
 print("here")
 state = learning_process.initialize()
 for round in range(rounds):
    print("inside")
    if round % 5 == 0:
        model_weights = learning_process.get_model_weights(state)
        metrics = eval_process(model_weights, [test_data])['eval']
    if round < 25 or round % 25 == 0:
        print(f'Round {round:3d}: {metrics}')
        data_frame = data_frame.append({'Round': round,
                                  'NoiseMultiplier': noise_multiplier,
                                  **metrics}, ignore_index=True)

  # Sample clients for a round. Note that if your dataset is large and
  # sampling_prob is small, it would be faster to use gap sampling.
    x = np.random.uniform(size=total_clients)
    sampled_clients = [
       train_data.client_ids[i] for i in range(total_clients)
    if x[i] < sampling_prob]
       sampled_train_data = [
       train_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client)
    for client in sampled_clients]

  # Use selected clients for update.
    result = learning_process.next(state, sampled_train_data)
    state = result.state
    metrics = result.metrics

    model_weights = learning_process.get_model_weights(state)
    metrics = eval_process(model_weights, [test_data])['eval']
    print(f'Round {rounds:3d}: {metrics}')
    data_frame = data_frame.append({'Round': rounds,
                              'NoiseMultiplier': noise_multiplier,
                              **metrics}, ignore_index=True)

 return data_frame
```